# ARM Multiply Negates MNEG

Tags: arm

Signed - SMNEGL,
Unsigned - UMNEGL,
?? - MNEG

Ok so what is the third multiply-negate (MNEG)?  There's a few operations like this one.  The descriptions are the exact same.  Is it just the same as unsigned or signed? I noticed MNEG has a 32-bit version while UMNEGL doesn't.

Comment: `mneg` is a 32x32→32 multiply, so the result is the same for both signed and unsigned.

Comment: So why have an UMNEGL?

Comment: For 32x32→64 multiply, the results depend on whether you treat the 32-bit inputs as signed or unsigned. Try it out for yourself. On a piece of paper, multiply `0x00000001` and `0xffffffff` as signed 32-bit numbers (producing a 64-bit result) and then as unsigned 32-bit (producing a 64-bit result).

Comment: for addition (and subtraction) because of twos complement the same logic works with signed and unsigned.   for multiply and divide you have to specify as there are fill/pad bits that are involved and signedness does matter.

Comment: this can easily be seen with pencil and paper and grade school long multiplication.  but using binary it is that much easier...

Comment: you have a series of basic questions about the arm instruction set, are you making a simulator or clone or something?  just read the arm docs instead of asking us to.

Comment: 0xab * 0x12 = 0x06.  signed or unsigned (look at the addition on pencil and paper).  but if you want a 16 bit result from two 8 bit operands is it 0x00ab * 0x0012  = 0x0c06 or is it 0xffab * 0x0012 = 0xFA06?  not the same answer.  You can see on pencil and paper that the lower 8 bits of the result come only from the lower bits of the operands, starting on the 9th bit you have to create a sign extension or zero padding...

Comment: I try to read the ARM manual but it's not always crystal clear.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down a bit.

First of all, multiplication by itself.  It comes in four flavors:

- 32 x 32 = 32 (i.e. multiply two 32-bit inputs and get a 32-bit output, with high bits truncated): e.g. `mul w0, w1, w2`.  There is no signed/unsigned version, because non-widening multiplication is bitwise the same operation for either signed or unsigned operands - a fact from modular arithmetic.
- 64 x 64 = 64, e.g. `mul x0, x1, x2`.  Same deal, no signed/unsigned distinction.
- 32 x 32 = 64 "long multiply", e.g. `smull x0, w1, w2`.  Here it does make a difference whether the operation is to work for signed or unsigned values, so we have separate `smull` and `umull` instructions.  For instance, `0xffffffff * 0xffffffff` should be `0x1` if treated as signed, or `0xfffffffe00000001` if treated as unsigned.  (But as noted above, the low 32 bits are the same for both.)
- 64 * 64 = 128.  This uses `mul / smulh` or `mul / umulh` depending on whether it should be signed or unsigned.  It's not directly relevant to your question.

Now, `mul` and `smull/umull` are also available as multiply-add and multiply-subtract operations, where for instance `madd w0, w1, w2, w3` computes `w0 = (w1 * w2) + w3`.  Likewise `smaddl x0, w1, w2, x3` computes `x0 = (w1 * w2) + x3`, with the multiplication done as signed 32x32=64, and `umaddl x0, w1, w2, x3` similar for unsigned.  Indeed, `mul w0, w1, w2` is just an alias of `madd w0, w1, w2, wzr`, and ditto for `smull` and `umull`.

As for the multiply-subtract versions, for instance `msub w0, w1, w2, w3` computes `w0 = w3 - (w1 * w2)`.  If the fourth operand is the zero register, then `msub w0, w1, w2, wzr` would compute `w0 = -(w1*w2)`.  For convenience, this instruction is aliased as `mneg w0, w1, w2`.  As above, it makes no difference whether you think of it as signed or unsigned, because it's the same binary operation either way.

The long versions likewise have a multiply-subtract, which becomes multiply-negate with the zero register.  `smnegl x0, w1, w2` computes `x0 = -(w1 * w2)`, signed widening, alias of `smsubl x0, w1, w2, xzr`.  Likewise `umnegl x0, w1, w2` computes `x0 = -(w1 * w2)`, unsigned widening.  You may think negation looks odd on an unsigned value, but it's all mod 2^64 so you can also think of it as `x0 = 2^64 - (w1 * w2)`.

There may not be much particular value in the multiply-negate instructions, but they come for free in the hardware as special cases of multiply-subtract when you use the zero register, so the ARM folks figured they might as well provide an alias in the assembler, just in case somebody found it useful.